# How to secure a ServerSocket so that other processes cannot use it?

Tags: java, android, serversocket

If a Java application creates a `ServerSocket` that accepts TCP connections, is there a way to restrict which processes are allowed to connect to it?

For example, this is my current code:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1234);
Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
```

and I want to make sure that other devices on my network and even other processes running on the same machine are not able to connect to it (it would be a security risk if they did). I was able to solve the former by binding `serverSocket` only to the loopback address (checking if `socket.getRemoteAddress()` points to the local host would work too) but I couldn't find a way to restrict it to my current process.

This is even more of a problem when doing it on Android. In my application, I want to create a `WebView` (owned by my process) and point it to `serverSocket` but I don't want others apps to be able to connect to it.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you can prevent other processes from connecting to the ServerSocket but you accept a connection you can definitely determine if it belongs to you or to some other process. The first step is figure out if the connection originated from localhost:

```
InetSocketAddress remoteAddress = (InetSocketAddress) socket.getRemoteSocketAddress();
String hostname = remoteAddress.getHostName();
if (!hostname.equals("localhost")) { socket.close(); }
```

Alternatively you can bind the socket to a loopback address like 127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0 (like EJP mentioned) and skip this step. Once you know that the connection came from localhost all you have to do is find the remote port and figure out if your process owns it.

```
int remotePort = remoteAddress.getPort();
if (ownPort(remotePort) == 1) { socket.close(); }
```

As far as I know, Java doesn't have an API that you can use to list your process ports but you can definitely do that via JNI. On the Java side you would need something like:

```
private native int doOwnPort(int port);
```

And on the native side:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_something_doOwnPort(JNIEnv *env, jobject object, jint port) {
    long totalFDs = getdtablesize();
    struct sockaddr_in sa;
    struct stat sb;
    // Iterate through all file descriptors
    for (int i = 0; i < totalFDs; ++i) {
        // Check if "i" is a valid FD
        memset(&sb, 0, sizeof(sb));
        if (fstat(i, &sb) < 0)
            continue;
        // Check if "i" is a socket
        if (!S_ISSOCK(sb.st_mode))
            continue;
        // Get local address of socket with FD "i"
        memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
        socklen_t sa_len = sizeof(sa);
        getsockname(i, (struct sockaddr*) &sa, &sa_len);
        // Check if the port matches
        if (sa.sin_port == port)
            return 1; // We own the port
    }
    return -1; // We don't own the port
}
```

PS: This code is for Linux but should work on Android/Windows/OSX too.

Maybe there is a more direct/efficient way to check if the port is owned by the current process without having to iterate through the FD table but that's a separate problem. HTH!

Comment: Thanks for this but I can't find `getdtablesize()` on Android. Can you show me where that is defined?

Comment: Use `#include <unistd.h>` or define it yourself like in here: https://github.com/OpenWireSec/metasploit/blob/master/external/source/meterpreter/source/bionic/libc/unistd/getdtablesize.c

Comment: Yey! That works! Apparently the Android NDK doesn't have `getdtablesize()` in `unistd.h` but I used the other implementation and it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind it to `127.0.0.1`,<sup>[1]</sup> which prevents any process outside the localhost from even seeing it. But any process in the localhost can connect to it. That being what it's for. If you want to restrict that to *certain* processes you will have to implement an authentication step in your protocol.

Hard to see why. If you can't trust other processes in the localhost you have a rather large problemm in general, not just here.

[1] Or indeed `127.0.0.x` where `1 <= x <= 254.` Using an obscure number like 200 might help by obscurity but it still isn't really secure.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this type of security

- using firewalls
- implementing some kind of authentication yourself on your ServerSocket. Ask for username and password?

Sockets were not designed for restricting to distinct processes.

Comment: Thanks but while a firewall would be useful to restrict access from other devices on the network, I don't see how it could protect against apps running on the same host. Custom authentication is a good idea and would solve my problem but it would it doesn't seem possible to customize 3rd party widgets to use it (like `WebView` on Android) since they don't give you access to their socket factories nor use the application-wide defaults like those set by `SSLContext.setDefault(...)` :(

Comment: to solve the webview thing you can very well use a JavaScriptInterface to implement the auth scheme of your choice,or even a custom protocol that you capture in the WebViewClient, like encrypted://mystuff

Answer (score 0):

From [Android Security Tips](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html#Networking):

> We have seen some applications use localhost network ports for handling sensitive IPC. We discourage this approach since these interfaces are accessible by other applications on the device. Instead, you should use an Android IPC mechanism where authentication is possible such as with a Service. (Even worse than using loopback is to bind to INADDR_ANY since then your application may receive requests from anywhere.)

Comment: Thanks mikkokoo! It's a shame that Google didn't add a way to customize the socket factory for webviews... it would just solve my problem. Maybe they do it in a future release of Android.